# size mismatch + ragged tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm having this problem which I'm unable to solve.
Has anyone had the same issue?
I'm using windows 10
Tensorflow 2

This is the command that I ran :
python test.py --model_architecture ds_cnn --model_size_info 5 64 10 4 2 2 64 3 3 1 1 64 3 3 1 1 64 3 3 1 1 64 3 3 1 1 --dct_coefficient_count 10 --window_size_ms 40 --window_stride_ms 20 --checkpoint ../Pretrained_models/DS_CNN/DS_CNN_S/ckpt/ds_cnn_0.94_ckpt

```
Untarring speech_commands_v0.02.tar.gz...
Running testing on validation set...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", 
line 206, in wrapper
return target(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", 
line 1838, in tensor_not_equals
return gen_math_ops.not_equal(self, other, incompatible_shape_error=False)
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 6573, in not_equal
ctx=_ctx)
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 6601, in not_equal_eager_fallback
_attr_T, _inputs_T = _execute.args_to_matching_eager([x, y], ctx, [])
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", 
line 280, in args_to_matching_eager
ret = [ops.convert_to_tensor(t, dtype, ctx=ctx) for t in l]
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", 
line 280, in
ret = [ops.convert_to_tensor(t, dtype, ctx=ctx) for t in l]
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py", line 163, in wrapped
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", 
line 1566, in convert_to_tensor
ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 339, in 
_constant_tensor_conversion_function
return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)  
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 265, in constant
allow_broadcast=True)
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 276, in _constant_impl
return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 301, in _constant_eager_impl
 t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, type)
File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 98, in convert_to_eager_tensor
 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, type)
 ValueError: TypeError: object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 182, in
 test()
 File "test.py", line 48, in test
 val_data = audio_processor.get_data(audio_processor.Modes.VALIDATION).batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
 File "C:\Users\x\Dropbox\Documents\x\Coding\KWS\tflu-kws-cortex-m\Training\data.py", line 
 190, in get_data
  use_background = (self.background_data != []) and (mode == AudioProcessor.Modes.TRAINING)
 File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 210, in wrapper
 result = dispatch(wrapper, args, kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 122, in dispatch
 result = dispatcher.handle(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow\python\ops\ragged\ragged_dispatch.py", line 219, in handle
  ragged_tensor_shape.RaggedTensorDynamicShape.from_tensor(y))
  File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow\python\ops\ragged\ragged_tensor_shape.py", line 470, in 
  broadcast_dynamic_shape
   shape_x = shape_x.broadcast_dimension(axis, shape_y.dimension_size(axis))
   File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\ops\ragged\ragged_tensor_shape.py", line 351, in 
   broadcast_dimension
      condition, data=broadcast_err, summarize=10)
    File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
     packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_should_use.py", line 247, in wrapped
      return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs),
      File "C:\Users\x\anaconda3\envs\newenvt\lib\site- 
      packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 164, in Assert
      (condition, "\n".join(data_str)))
      tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, 
      shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'Unable to broadcast: dimension 
      size mismatch in dimension'
       1
        b'lengths='
         0
            b'dim_size='
        1522930, 988891, 980062, 960000, 978488, 960000`
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi @ Ran , This might be a ragged tensor issue  as I see "Unable to broadcast: dimension size mismatch in dimension...." at the end of error.  It might occur that involved ragged tensors are not broad casting  . Can you please try with the syntax details here in this link .https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#broadcasting , you will also find the similar exceptions after this section.

Comment: Thank you @TensorflowSupport. The issue was TensorFlow compatibility. The code I was using was for TensorFlow 2.3 and I was having Tensorflow 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was TensorFlow compatibility. Downgrading from TensorFlow 2.5 to 2.3 fixes the problem.